# Implement Custom Shortcut keys in winforms dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts, infragistics

My winform project has a menu, now I would like to create a form that allows assignment of custom shortcut keys at runtime to the menu items. Is there a plugin in visual studio to do that?

---

**EDIT:**
My project is mainly using infragistics and thus wanted to know if this kind of facility is provided by Infragistics

Comment: why infragistics tag?

Comment: because i want to know if infragistics provides this kind of facility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Shortcut](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinToolbars.v14.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.SharedProps~Shortcut.html) Property on the SharedProps of the tool that you want the shortcut for.

Note that you are limited to Shortcut key combinations in the [Shortcut Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Windows.Forms.Shortcut%29&rd=true).